# Cannot pull Docker image out of OpenShift cluster

Tags: docker, openshift

I would like to pull a Docker image that was built inside an OpenShift Container Platform 3.9 cluster out of that cluster. To this end I try [the following](https://blog.openshift.com/remotely-push-pull-container-images-openshift/):

```
username=$(oc whoami)
api_token=$(oc whoami -t)
docker login -u $username -p $api_token my-cluster:443
image=$(oc get is/my-is -o jsonpath='{.status.tags[0].items[0].dockerImageReference}')
docker pull $image
```

Now `docker login` works, but `docker image` produces the error message

> lookup docker-registry.default.svc on 1.2.3.4: no such host

where `1.2.3.4` is a placeholder for my local nameserver according to `/etc/resolv.conf` and  `$image` is of the form `docker-registry.default.svc:5000/registry/my-is@sha256:my-id`.
Am I doing something wrong or could it be that the cluster administrator must first [expose the registry](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/registry/securing_and_exposing_registry.html) (but should it not be exposed by default)? If I try `oc get svc -n default` as suggested [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/16097) I get this error message:

> User "my-user" cannot list services in project "default"

So what steps are needed (preferably without intervention by the cluster's administrator) for me successfully pulling out that image? Would the situation change if the pull occurred in a container also executing inside the OpenShift cluster?

Comment: ``docker-registry.default.svc`` is a hostname that only works within the cluster. You need to work out what the external hostname for the internal image registry is. May only apply for certain OpenShift cluster setups, but external image registry hostname may be visible in web console. See http://cookbook.openshift.org/image-registry-and-image-streams/how-do-i-push-an-image-to-the-internal-image-registry.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lead provided in a comment was the right one. (Thanks!). The following script now does work; no intervention by a cluster admin was required:

```
username=$(oc whoami)
api_token=$(oc whoami -t)
docker login -u $username -p $api_token my-cluster:443
docker pull my-cluster:443/my-project/my-is
docker images
```